# Focus on terminal in editor group

Tags: visual-studio-code

Now that it is possible to create a terminal in the editor area is there a way to send focus to a terminal in an editor area? Or, would this only be possible through `workbench.action.focus*`?

Currently I utilise the CTRL + J keyboard shortcut to focus on the integrated terminal. I would like to replicate this behaviour but with terminals in the editor area.